# Elements of graded algebra associated with the algebra of differential operators as smooth sections

Tags: vector-bundles, differential-operators, index-theory

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $E$ a complex vector bundle. We will consider differential operators $P$ acting between $\Gamma^{\infty}(M,E)$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the algebra of all differential operators: then $\mathcal{P}$ is *filtered*. Once we have filtered algebra, we can associate the *graded* algebra $\mathcal{S}$ as follows: $\mathcal{S}^d:=\mathcal{P}^d/\mathcal{P}^{d-1}$. Note that $\mathcal{P}^0=\mathcal{S}^0=C^{\infty}(M)$. When $P$ and $Q$ have degrees $m$ and $n$ (resp.) then $[P,Q]$ has degree $m+n-1$. In particular $[P,f]$ has degree $m-1$ for a smooth function $f$. From this it follows that $C^{\infty}(M)$ is central in $\mathcal{S}$. This should allow us to realize elements in $\mathcal{S}$ as smooth sections of some vector bundle $U$: here $U_x$ is defined as $\mathcal{S}/I_x \mathcal{S}$ where $I_x$ is the ideal of all smooth functions vanishing at $x$.

> Why $\mathcal{S}$ is isomorphic with $\Gamma^{\infty}(M,U)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector space $U_x$ will be infinite dimensional, so it's not immediately clear what $\Gamma^\infty(M,U)$ denotes. I assume you mean $\Gamma^\infty(M,U):=\bigoplus_k \Gamma^\infty(M,U^k)$ where $U^k_x:=\mathcal{S}^k/I_x\mathcal{S}^k$. Then the question might be: Why is $\mathcal{S}^k$ isomorphic to $\Gamma^\infty(M,U^k)$? When $\mathcal{S}^k$ is projective an finitely generated over $C^\infty(M)$ (which I think it is in your setting) the answer is the [Serre-Swan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem). You can find a proof for the $C^\infty$ setting in the book Nestruev, Smooth manifolds and observables.

**Added in response to the comment:**

You wrote:

> Serre-Swan's theorem gives you that $\mathcal{S}^k$ can be identified with $\Gamma^\infty(M,V)$ for *some* vector bundle $V$ (provided we can show that $\mathcal{S}^k$ is finitely generated and projective). 
>   On the other hand, here we would like to have a concrete description of $V$ as $U$ where the fiber over $x$ is $\mathcal{S}^k/I_x\mathcal{S}^k$.

That concrete description *always* follows from an identification $\Gamma^\infty(M,V)=\mathcal{S}^k$. To be precise: from a vector bundle $V$, a $C^\infty(M)$-module $\mathcal{P}$ and a $C^\infty(M)$-module isomorphism $\phi: \Gamma^\infty(M,V)\to \mathcal{P}$, we always obtain a natural identification $V_x= \mathcal{P}/I_x\mathcal{P}$. This identification is constructed as follows: given $x\in M$, let's consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a $C^\infty(M)$-module via the canonical identification $C^\infty(M)/I_x = \mathbb{R}$. Next we have a natural identification
$\mathcal{P}/I_x\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P}\otimes_{C^\infty M} \mathbb{R}$, given in the direction 
$
\mathcal{P}/I_x\mathcal{P}\to \mathcal{P}\otimes_{C^\infty M} \mathbb{R}
$
by
$$
p  \text{ mod }  I_x\mathcal{P}\mapsto p\otimes 1
$$
and in the other direction by
$$
p\otimes c \mapsto p\cdot c \text{ mod } I_x\mathcal{P}.
$$
(I skip the details of verifying that these maps are well defined and yield the identity when composed. Feel free to ask if something is not clear.)

Hence, tensoring the isomorphism $\phi$ with $\mathbb{R}$ we obtain an identification 
$$
\alpha: \Gamma^\infty(M,V)/I_x\Gamma^\infty(M,V) \to \mathcal{P} /I_x\mathcal{P}.
$$
As last step, it's not hard to see that $\Gamma^\infty(M,V)/I_x\Gamma^\infty(M,V)$  is naturally identified with $V_x$
for any vector bundle $V$ (Corollary 11.9 in Nestruev).

To see that your concrete module $\mathcal{S}^k$ is finitely generated and projective we can construct an isomorphism $\mathcal{S}^k = \mathcal{Q}^*\otimes_{C^\infty(M)} \mathcal{Q}\otimes_{C^\infty(M)} S^k D$, where I'm using the following abbreviations

- $\mathcal{Q} =\Gamma^\infty(M,E)$
- $D$ denotes the module of vector fields on $M$, i.e. sections of the tangent bundle,
- $S^k$ denotes the $k$-th symmetric product of a $C^\infty(M)$-module.
- $\mathcal{Q}^*=\text{Hom}_{C^\infty M}(Q,C^\infty M)$,

In one direction this iso is defined by
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{Q}^*\otimes_{C^\infty M} \mathcal{Q}\otimes_{C^\infty M} S^k D &\to \mathcal{P}^k/\mathcal{P}^{k-1}\\
  r\otimes s \otimes (X_1\cdots X_k) &\mapsto s\circ X_1\circ\ldots\circ X_k \circ r \quad \text{mod} \quad \mathcal{P}^{k-1}
\end{align}

To make sense of the composition with $s$, use the canonical identification of a module $\mathcal{Q}$ with $\text{Hom}_{C^\infty M}(C^\infty M, \mathcal{Q})$.

The other direction is also not to hard to define, but slightly more involved: start with the observation that given $(\nabla \text{ mod } \mathcal{P}^{k-1}) \in \mathcal{P}^k/\mathcal{P}^{k-1}$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in C^\infty M$, then $[\cdots [\nabla,a_1],a_2]\cdots ,a_k]\in \mathcal{Q}^*\otimes \mathcal{Q}$ is well-defined (independent of the representative $\nabla\in \mathcal{P}^k$) and multilinear symmetric and a derivation in the $a_i$'s. From there you can use the universal derivation $d: A \to \Lambda^1$ (differential one forms) to show that you get a well defined map from $ \mathcal{P}^k/\mathcal{P}^{k-1}$ to $\mathcal{Q}^*\otimes_{C^\infty(M)} \mathcal{Q}\otimes_{C^\infty(M)} S^k D$.

This identification not only shows that $\mathcal{S}^k$ is projective and finitely generated, it gives a more concrete description of fibers $\mathcal{S}^k/I_x\mathcal{S}^k$: they are symbols $S^k T_xM\otimes_\mathbb{R} \text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(E_x,E_x)$, as mentioned in Peter Michor's answer.

Comment: You are right about the finitness of dimension. However, I still don't see why $\mathcal{S}^k$ need to be projective and finitely generated.

Comment: I think you can also find a proof of that in the Nestruev book.

Comment: If i recall correctly, you can define a natural iso $\mathcal{S}^d\to S^d X\otimes \mathcal{S}^0$. The first factor of the tensor product is the symmetric power of derivations on $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: Still I don't see how to finish the argument. Serre-Swan'ts theorem gives you that $\mathcal{S}^k$ can be identified with $\Gamma^{\infty}(M,V^k)$ for _some_ vector bundle $V^k$ (provided we can show that $\mathcal{S}^k$ is finitely generated and projective). On the other hand, here we would like to have a concrete description of $V^k$ as $U^k$ where the fiber over $x$ is $\mathcal{S}^k/ I_x \mathcal{S}$. As far as I know, somehow we have to use the fact that $C^{\infty}(M)$ is central in $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @truebaran I tried to address your comment in my edit, which I rewrote now.

Comment: @truebaran I tried to simplify my reply to your comment. Have a look and let me know if you see something missing.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation! It seems that once you have identified our module $\mathcal{S_k}$ as $\Gamma(M,U_k)$ for some bundle then we have a short exact sequence of the form $0 \to I_x \mathcal{S}_k \to \mathcal{S}_k \to  (U_k)_x \to 0$. Therefore I'm more interested in the second identification of the bundle $U_k$ in terms of symmetric powers. I would be happy if you can also adress the following issues: how to define the inverse isomorphism (is this map which you described well defined? We compose $r$ with succesive vector fields but at the end we compose with $s$ thus the whole ...)

Comment: ...thing take a section $t \in \Gamma(M,E)$, produces a smooth function on which we act then by differential operator. This produces another smooth function and finally we want to compose with $s$ but does this composition make sens?). I would be also very happy if you could please explain me the following issue: each symbol may be viewed as a _section_ acting $T^*M \to Hom(p^*E,p^*F)$ where $p$ is the projection or as a _morphism_ of bundles $p^*E \to p^*F$. In both these descriptions the symmetric power does not appear. What am I missing?

Comment: @truebaran I gave a few more details about the isomorphism with symmetric powers in the answer. Concerning your last question, maybe you're missing that the symmetric algebra over vector fields embeds canonically into $C^\infty (T^*M)$ as fiberwise polynomial functions on the cotangent. Hence a symbol in the sense of my answer becomes a section in your sense.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer: as you can see I accepted your answer as well awarded you with the bounty. I'm going to analyze all the details, thank you once again!

Comment: You’re welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal S$ is the space of symbols. The approach that you sketch in your question is elaborated in the following paper, in a quite lucid way, if I remember correctly:

- MR0739951 (85j:58150a)
  Vinogradov, A. M.(2-MOSC)
  The $\mathcal C$-spectral sequence, Lagrangian formalism, and conservation laws. I. The linear theory. 
  J. Math. Anal. Appl. 100 (1984), no. 1, 1–40. 
  58G37 (35A30 58A17 58G35)

Comment: Not quite the space of symbols: obviously the idea is to call by a ,,symbol'' objects which take into account only the highest order term of a differential operator but genuine symbol are sections over $T^*M$ of the bundle $Hom(E,F)$. The paper which you mention is interesting but I don't see how it provides the answer (for example the last Proposition in zeroth section is without proof).